# Using System.Dynamic not recognized

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I am using Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4.X and I'm trying to use the ExpandoObject class, but I'm getting a not recognized error on the `using System.Dynamic` statement.

I made sure to add a reference to `System.Core`, but that didn't resolve the issue. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Are you compiling for .NET 4.0 or higher?

Comment: "Are you missing an assembly reference?".  Yes.

Comment: Yes, I  am missing an assembly reference

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a reference to the assembly `System.Core`.

To do this, find your project in the solution explorer, right click "References", and click "Add Reference...". Then, in the assemblies list, find `System.Core`, and add it.

Comment: Where can I download the Dynamic reference ?

Comment: @O.Deitch you don't need to download it. You just need to add a reference. I updated the answer to explain how.

Comment: THANKS Got It! I added the reference to the assembly but it still DOESN'T WORK...

Comment: I added the assembly reference but it does not recognize using system.dynamic what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Core assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This moved to System.Dynamic at some point.